# C - Sorting linked lists at insertion

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I am looking to get some help understanding on how I would implement a sorted linked list at the point of insertion? Below is an `addItem` function with the option to add at the beginning of the list or at the end. Is it possible to insert (thereby sorting) depending on the value given in  `var.number;` for example?

```
struct structName {
    int number;
    int number2;
    char aString;
    struct structName *next;
};

struct structName *head = NULL;
struct structName *curr = NULL;
struct structName *element = NULL;

struct Struct var;

struct structName* addItem(struct structName var, bool appendList) {

    struct structName *pointer = (struct structName*)malloc(sizeof(struct structName));

    pointer->someString = var.aString;
    pointer->aNumber = var.number2;
    pointer->anotherNumber = var.number;
    pointer->next = NULL;

    if(appendList) {
        curr->next = pointer;
        curr = pointer;
    }
    else {
        pointer->next = head;
        head = pointer;
    }  

    return pointer;
}
```

Comment: There are **countless** questions concerning linked lists. I'm sure you'll find your answer on Google or by searching StackOverflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you insert into a sorted linked list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320460/how-do-you-insert-into-a-sorted-linked-list)

Answer (score 0):

it's simple. if you want to insert into a sorted list. Then before inserting the list you have to traverse through the list, until you go to the end of list or find a node value which is greater than the current list value. Then Insert your list.

Comment: ...in this way the list remains sorted but you may not accept commands like "insert at head" or" insert at end" because then the list becomes unsorted.